# How to 'unimport' scripts in lldb

Tags: debugging, lldb

The commands in `~/.lldbinit` that gets imported before each debugging session.
I have a bunch of `command script imports` in the `~/.lldbinit` file.

At some point I don't want those commands. Is this possible while continuing the same debugging session?

Answer (score 2):

That wasn't possible till quite recently.  In the current TOT version of lldb you can put commands into "containers" - in the same way built-in commands like `process launch` etc. can.  That's reduces the motivation to remove the commands, since they don't clutter up the command namespace.  The  new feature allows you to delete parts of your container hierarchy as well.  I don't think this has made it to the major distro's yet, however.

The new command that does this is `command container`.